# document.write nested in document.write

Tags: javascript, document.write

I have an ad tag that a third party is trying to stuff inside of a 'document.write' function and it's not working because the ad tag itself also contains document.write's.  Is there a way to shove this ad tag inside of a single instance of document.write?  If so, please help me figure this out and if not, is there an alternative?

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
var m3_u = 'http://this.that.com/adtag.js';
var m3_r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 99999999999);
var category='999';

if (!document.MAX_used) 
    document.MAX_used = ',';

document.write("<scr" + "ipt type='text/javascript' src='" + m3_u);
document.write("?c=" + category +"&amp;b=Sampletag&amp;p=ptnr&amp;key=4984cc8f3064e22a4e29fb2b3b2e9cb5");
document.write('&amp;cb=' + m3_r);

if (document.MAX_used != ',') 
    document.write("&amp;exclude=" + document.MAX_used);

document.write(document.charset ? '&amp;charset=' + document.charset :
(document.characterSet ? '&amp;charset=' + document.characterSet : ''));
document.write("&amp;loc=" + escape(window.location));

if (document.referrer) 
    document.write("&amp;referer=" + escape(document.referrer));
if (document.context) 
    document.write("&context=" + escape(document.context));
if (document.mmm_fo) 
    document.write("&amp;mmm_fo=1");

document.write("'><\/scr" + "ipt>");
</script>
```

Comment: JavaScript and HTML5 are the future of modern programming?

Answer (score 1):

document.write is often concidered a harmful method, as it directly inserts content into the document file itself. You should edit the innerHTML of the tag where you want to insert the code, although I've heard that directly using innerHTML isn't the correct way either. The method is called insertNode, If I'm remembering correctly, but I'm not sure, because I'm usually abstracting this type of problem away using frameworks such as jQuery, where it is as simple as

```
$("#myelement").html("<script>...</script>")
```

I hope that some of my fellow SO members can make this post more precise, I'll look some stuff up myself, but concider this to be my quick answer.

Comment: Since he has no evidence of jQuery in his example, use `document.getElementById('#element').innerHTML = '<script>...</script>';`