# Nested document.writes and third party ads not working in IE!!!! Any workaround that is safe?

Tags: javascript, jquery

**NOTE: I edited this with more info of what I am getting back from the third party.**

In a nutshell I have a task to include a JS ad tag that calls to our internal ad server mechanism which then retries a third party script that document.writes to their external file... it will not work in IE. Someone mentioned to me that nested document.writes will not work in IE. I have tried various things.. appendTo / writeln / breaking up the script tag / decoding the script tags etc.. nothing seems to work. Since this is somewhat new to me, perhaps I am overlooking the obvious.

This is what it looks like:

```
my html:
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
   document.write('\x3Cscript type="text/javascript" src="_some_Path_to_internal_ad_server">\x3C/script>';);
</script>
```

That call ends up bringing in some code that looks like this: just as you see, no enclosing script tags.

```
   tl1 = '989';
   tl2 = 'xnlll';
   document.write('<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"_some_Path_to_third_party.js\"><\/script>');
```

Now, that "_some_Path_to_third_party.js" brings in some js code that has document.writes and document.writeln

I am writing this off the top of my head, so I don't remember exactly how the script tags are broken up, but I don't believe that is the issue. I believe it is the nested document.writes in IE.

I tried various things and even laid out my first script call right in my page. No document.writes -- just

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="_some_Path_to_internal_ad_server">
```

No dice.

BUT a direct call to the external js did work (removing my call to my internal ad server which subsequently calls the third party call), ala:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="_some_Path_to_internal_ad_server">
```

Anyone have experience dealing with anything likes this and how to overcome it?

Comment: Sidenote: _language attribute is not valid._

Comment: On the last script you posted, you meant `_some_Path_to_third_party.js` right?

Comment: Also, which versions of IE have you tested in?

Comment: In the second `document.write()` you are escaping double quotes from a string enclosed with single quotes. May IE not handle this situation correctly?

Comment: `<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
   document.write('\x3Cscript type="text/javascript" src="_some_Path_to_internal_ad_server">\x3C/script>';);
</script>` Why is this layer there in the first place. Why not just link directly to the internal ad server?

Comment: Any [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) maybe? *"I am writing this off the top of my head, so I don't remember exactly how the script tags are broken up"* - Well, if you don't know then how do you expect anyone here to know? If you are sure that the problem is with nested document.write calls then this is a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7450762/document-write-nested-in-document-write).

Comment: Quad-ExclamationMark not working on me.

Answer (score 6):

Since you didn't post enough details to write a complete answer to your problem (you write: "I am writing this off the top of my head, so I don't remember exactly how the script tags are broken up") so here are some general tips to get you started instead of a direct solution. You say that you are convinced that the problem is with too much of `document.write` calls so I will concentrate on minimizing their number wherever possible. Hopefully it will let you eventually solve your problem.

## Extra semicolon

In your first example you have:

```
document.write(' ... ';);
```

Removing the extra semicolon it would be:

```
document.write(' ... ');
```

Could that be causing some problems? If not then read on...

First of all some basics:

## Script type and language

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
```

The "language" attribute is deprecated so don't use it. The problem with the "type" attribute is that text/javascript MIME type is obsolete (see [RFC4329](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4329.txt)) and application/javascript (the correct type) is not universally supported. In practice every browser has always known that without "type" it's just JavaScript and that's why I recommend to leave it out for every markup version where it is optional, like HTML5. (Besides the MIME type is something that should be specified by the server.) See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2267476/html-script-tag-type-or-language) for more info. That having been said, I will just use `<script>` in the examples below.

## Minimizing document writes

Having this in your HTML:

```
<script>
    document.write('\x3Cscript src="file.js">\x3C/script>');
</script>
```

Is exactly equivalent to:

```
<script src="file.js"></script>
```

It make so sense to use `document.write` in this case, unless you are building the script name dynamically in JavaScript or something like that, but even then you can do it without `document.write`.

If you don't know the path of your script and you are using eg. a JavaScript variable named `path` then you may be tempted to write something like this:

```
<script>
    document.write('\x3Cscript src="' + path + '">\x3C/script>');
</script>
```

But you can achieve pretty much the same result with something similar to what Google uses for Analytics:

```
var newScript = document.createElement('script');
newScript.src = path; // or newScript.src = 'file.js';
var firstScript = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScript.parentNode.insertBefore(newScript, firstScript);
```

Or shorter, using `appendChild`:

```
var newScript = document.createElement('script');
newScript.src = path; // or newScript.src = 'file.js';
document.body.appendChild(newScript);
```

Or easier using jQuery:

```
$('<script />', {src: path}).appendTo('body');
```

where `path` is the URL of your script. Or partially using jQuery just for the insertion into the DOM:

```
var newScript = document.createElement('script');
newScript.src = path; // or newScript.src = 'file.js';
$('body').append(newScript);
```

You may also be able to use jQuery.getScript:

```
$.getScript(path);
```

## More ideas

For other ideas see:

- [Google Analytics code asynchronous syntax](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/)
- [Google Analytics code traditional syntax](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingOverview) (with `document.write`)
- [jQuery getScript](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/)
- [YUI Get](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/get/)
- [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/)

These are some basic things you can do to minimize the use of `document.write`. Hopefully this will get you started.