# Is there a way to fix nested document.write in window.open?

Tags: javascript, window.open, document.write, new-window

I have a button that will open a new blank window using `window.open`, but will write a multiplication table on it.

Here's my code.

```js
document.getElementById("p").innerHTML = "<button id = 'mult' type = 'button'>Multiplication Tables</button>";
document.getElementById("mult").onclick = function() {
  newWindow()
};
document.getElementById("close").onclick = function() {
  close()
};

function newWindow() {
  var multiplyWindow = window.open("", "multiplicationTables", "width = 300, height = 200");
  multiplyWindow.document.write(multiply());
}

function multiply() {
  document.write("<center><table border='1px'>");
  for (var a = 5; a < 11; a++) {
    document.write("<tr style='height:40px'>");
    for (var b = 5; b < 11; b++) {
      document.write("<td style='width:40px'><center><font size='4'>" + a * b + "</center></font></td>");
    }
    document.write("</tr>");
  }
}
```

```html
<p id="p"></p>
```

I know the problem is because when I run the `multiply()` function, we are nesting a `document.write`. I thought of using `document.getElementById`, but the problem with that is (I think) there is no ID of a new window opened using `window.open`.

Instead, what happens is the multiplication table is printed on the original window, and in the new pop-up window, an "undefined" message shows up. This makes sense, again because of the nested `document.write`s.

---

Two questions:

1. How do I fix this nested `document.write` and still get it to work?
2. Is there a way to assign an ID to a new window using `window.open`?

---

Additionally, I look at this SO post: [document.write nested in document.write](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7450762/document-write-nested-in-document-write), but the only answer was simply not to use `document.write`.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Answer IS simply not to use document.write.

Comment: I made you a snippet. I had to add a `"` after `</button>` but there are other stuff going on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from DO NOT USE DOCUMENT.WRITE

you cannot "nest"

change

```js
function multiply() {
  document.write("<center><table border='1px'>");
  for (var a = 5; a < 11; a++) {
    document.write("<tr style='height:40px'>");
    for (var b = 5; b < 11; b++) {
      document.write("<td style='width:40px'><center><font size='4'>" + a * b + "</center></font></td>");
    }
    document.write("</tr></table>");
  }
}
```

to not document.write but return html

```js
function multiply() {
  const html = []
  html.push("<center><table border='1px'>");
  for (var a = 5; a < 11; a++) {
    html.push("<tr style='height:40px'>");
    for (var b = 5; b < 11; b++) {
      html.push("<td style='width:40px'><center><font size='4'>" + a * b + "</center></font></td>");
    }
    html.push("</tr>");
  }
  return html.join("")
}


function newWindow() {
  const multiplyWindow = window.open("", "multiplicationTables", "width=300,height=200");
  if (multiplyWindow) {
    multiplyWindow.document.write(multiply());
    multiplyWindow.document.close(); // important
  }  
  else alert("sorry, popups are blocked");
}

const p = document.getElementById("p");
p.innerHTML = "<button class='mult' type='button'>Multiplication Tables</button>";
p.addEventListener("click",function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.classList.contains("mult")) newWindow()
})
```

```html
<p id="p"></p>
```